# Automation in Excel for shift patterns

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, automation, lookup

Hi I have the following two tables

[image]

I am trying to get the col

I am trying to automate `Column E` so that every time the data changes in cell `D2` it would automatically get changed based on the shift patter that the Agent is assigned on that day.

I cannot used `vlookup` because it will obviously just take the first text found with for example `9am-5pm` - all cells would be populated with `Agent 3`.

Comment: It can't be seen how different dates would impact your result. We see only one place where you have dates, it's `D2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this array formula in `E3` in part does what you want (it is entered not using usual **Enter** key, but instead, **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**).

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(D3=$B$2:$B$10,ROW($B$2:$B$10)-ROW($B$2)+1),COUNTIF($D$3:D3,D3)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,AGGREGATE(15,3,($B$2:$B$10=D3)/($B$2:$B$10=D3)*ROW($B$2:$B$10)-1,COUNTIF(D$3:D3,D3)))`

As an alternate approach to ZygD's answer.

It uses AGGREGATE. It checks for the values in the B column range to equal the value in column D and divides the result by itself, which will result in 1 if True and multiplies that by the row number. The result gives the row numbers of all TRUEs and checks for the Nth smallest value based on how many of the same agent are already found in your result list above and finally shows the value of that row in your range of values in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Use XLOOKUP() instead. Column position does not matter with this function.

Comment: Can you show how xlookup() will work here?

Comment: XLOOKUP would return either the first or the last match. To get the second or third match XLOOKUP needs just as much help of extra formulas as ZygD's solution.

Comment: I didn't read the situation closely enough. XLOOKUP runs into the same problem as VLOOKUP().